# PHP chained class methods merged with other classes

Tags: php, merge, append, addition, chain

I start with an example.

**Mold class**

```php
<?php
class Mold {
  public $current;

  function merge($first, $second) {
    $this->current = $first . $second;
    return $this;
  }

  function phone() {
    $this->current = '<a href="tel:' . $this->current . '">' . $this->current . '</a>';
    return $this;
  }

  function __toString() {
    return $this->current;
  }
}

function mold() {
  return new Mold();
}
```

**In action**

This works as expected.

```php
echo mold()->merge('sada', 'asdsa')->phone();
```

### Problem

I have one or more classes with methods that wants to be available as well.

**Plugin class**

```php
class MyPlugin {
  function link() {
    // Code
  }

  function currency($number) {
    // Code
  }
}
```

```php
class MyPlugin2 {
  // Other methods
}
```

**Dream code**

The exact change of events below may not make any sense. Anyway, what I intend to do is the following.

```php
echo mold()->merge('sada', 'asdsa')->currency(45)-link();
```

- Call `mold()` which creates a new instance of the `Mold` class.
- Chain `merge()` which is used from the `Mold` class.
- `currency()` or `link()` method does not exist in the `Mold` class. Instead they should be loaded from one of the plugins.

### In conclusion

- I know I can extend a class but it does not really solve the problem because  there can be more than one plugin classes.
- I know I can create instances of the plugin classes, but they somehow need to be aware by the `Mold` class.
- Append methods to a class comes to mind as well as merge classes.

Comment: Make a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) of these methods.

Comment: How do you propose to get the plugins, dynamically by scanning a directory or you already know which ones will be available?

Comment: @vivek_23 It looks like this could be exactly what I need. Will do some tests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Interesting ideas.

The one that solves the problem like I had in my mind was to use [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.precedence) like @vivek_23 suggested in a comment.

**Here is a complete example of how it works**

```php
<?php
// Core methods
class MoldCore {
  public $current;

  function merge($first, $second) {
    $this->current = $first . $second;
    return $this;
  }

  function phone() {
    $this->current = '<a href="tel:' . $this->current . '">' . $this->current . '</a>';
    return $this;
  }

  function __toString() {
    return $this->current;
  }
}

// Plugin 1
trait Plugin1 {
  public function yaay() {
    $this->current .= ' Plugin1 yaay';
    return $this;
  }
}

// Plugin 2
trait Plugin2 {
  public function hello() {
    $this->current = str_replace('Plugin1', 'Modified', $this->current);
    return $this;
  }

  public function world() {
    $this->current .= ' Plugin2 world';
    return $this;
  }
}

// Glue plugins with MoldCore
class Mold extends MoldCore {
  use Plugin1, Plugin2;
}

$mold = new Mold();
echo $mold->merge('sada', 'asdsa')->phone()->yaay()->hello();
```

Comment: Extending the `MoldCore` class just to use the traits it's useless.
If the plugins are traits or could be turned into traits without affecting the rest of the code (and with them having "sense" in being a trait) just define the `use` statements` in the base class

Comment: @RiccardoCedrola You mean put `use Plugin1, Plugin2` into `MoldCore` class? That's not a good idea. Think of it as a big system where you use plugins. You want to use plugins without hacking the core of the system. To make `MoldCore` class intact, but still allow plugins, I need a bridge between them. If I understand you wrong, or you think you have a better idea, you can update your answer and I will look at it again.

Comment: Ok now I've understood the situation, if you shouldn't be modifying your `MoldCore` class, then it's fine to do this trick. I just assumed you were free to modify that class since you changed the name of it and since you modified the two plugins by turning them into traits.
If you have these kinds of limitations your solution will work the best

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could use `__call()` for this. Your "main" class could contain/track a set of plugin instances and any unknown method call could be looked up and delegated, if available in a plugin.

I wouldn't recommend this though. Fluent APIs are often brittle and can get inconvenient even with *one* class. Involving multiple classes in fluent calls might quickly to add up to a confusing mess. A mess which even IDE can't help you (or another person working with code) with since it has no clue about all the magic happening.

I would highly recommend to look into alternative patterns for an API like this.

Answer (score 0):

A concept that you might try to apply is the [Composition Over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

A solution could be to compose your current `Mold`object and pass the two plugins instances so that it could use them on its methods, like so:

```
<?php
class Mold {
  public $current;

  public function __construct(Plugin1 $plugin1, Plugin2 $plugin2) {
      $this->plugin1 = $plugin1;
      $this->plugin2 = $plugin2;
  }

  public function merge($first, $second) {
    $this->current = $first . $second;
    return $this;
  }

  public function phone() {
    $this->current = '<a href="tel:' . $this->current . '">' . $this->current . '</a>';
    return $this;
  }

  public function __toString() {
    return $this->current;
  }

  public function link() {
      $this->plugin1->link();
      return $this;
  }
}

function mold() {
  return new Mold(new Plugin1(), new Plugin2());
}
```

Another solution could be to create a `MoldHandler` class of some sort, which has a `Mold` object as a property together with the other plugins, which could be used inside of this directly.

```
public class MoldHanlder {

    protected $mold;
    protected $plugin1;
    protected $plugin2;

    public function __contruct($mold, $plugin1, $plugin2) {
        $this->mold    = $mold;
        $this->plugin1 = $plugin1;
        $this->plugin2 = $plugin2;
    }

    public function merge() {
        $this->mold = $this->mold->merge();
        return $this;
    }

    public function link() {
        $foo = $this->plugin1->method();

        return $this;
    }

    ...
}
```

You could also just instantiate the classes inside the `construct`, but if you are planning about writing unit tests, dependency injection is the way to go

I think that the first approach is way better because you avoid yourself to re-write some code of the Mold class, which is unnecessary

N.B. this is a really raw solution proposed just to let you better understand the idea I would opt for
cheers

Comment: Isn't this infinite? `$this->mold = $this->mold->merge();`

Comment: `mold` is not a method, is the property inside the `MoldHandler`, which contains a `Mold` instance.
the `merge` method of `Mold` does some stuff and then returns itself. So:
`$this->mold = $this->mold->merge();` just updates the `mold` property with the object returned by `merge`

Comment: Btw you give me a better idea on how to solve this, just compose the `Mold` class with the two plugins as properties, doing so it could access those methods directly from its object.
I updated my anser

Comment: @RiccardoCedrola Thanks! I however have found a more simple solution. It would turn your "MoldHandler" into only 3 lines of code. See my answer.

Comment: If you are able to turn the two plugins into traits without affecting the rest of your code, the subdivision between `Mold` and `MoldCore` is useless, just let `Mold` use the traits...

P.s. if you want an advice: always avoid extending classes if is not strictly necessary